# Error with gzipInflate/gzipDeflate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, ios

I develop an Iphone application on Xcode 4.0. I have to format an HTML file and put it into a Txt view. I'm trying to use TBXML , but i have 6 errors when I debug:

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataAdditions) gzipDeflate] in NSDataAdditions.o
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataAdditions) gzipDeflate] in NSDataAdditions.o
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataAdditions) gzipDeflate] in NSDataAdditions.o
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataAdditions) gzipInflate] in NSDataAdditions.o
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataAdditions) gzipInflate] in NSDataAdditions.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[NSData(NSDataAdditions) gzipInflate] in NSDataAdditions.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Something with gZip library i guess... If somebody know an issue to fix that or an other good/complete XMLParse library, thanks to answer me :D

PS: If you had some difficults to read, i'm sorry for my english...

Comment: YoshK, It would be nice if you accepted the answer of deanWornbourne (assuming it solved the problem).

Answer (score 27):

This type of error means that you haven't included a library or framework.

A quick Google of deflateInit2 tells me it's the libz framework.

If you add libz.dylib to your list of frameworks it should compile.

Hope that helps.

Comment: FYI : I think that using the library name without numbers defaults to the latest available version so I get whatever is on the system, while you _require_ that it be version 1.2.3 (I think. I might be wrong!).

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper I agree :) Unfortunately, YoshK was last seen 28th Apr last year so it's unlikely to happen now :(

Comment: @deanWombourne: no problem..i gave you a +1 from my side :)

Comment: it solved my Error but sdk(Gigya) is not giving responce after using this framwork.